# Google Maps V3 icon at the end of PolyLine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app that tracks the position of the sun and with it a poly-line that shows the current position of the sun. I want to put an icon at the end of the poly that follows it round the circle but the icon seems to revolve around the end of the line rather than staying static.

It's hard to explain with just code but an example can be seen [here](http://staging.sun-map.com)

Here is the code I'm using to draw the icon (which by the way is 26x26)

```
var _g = google.maps;

var image = {
    url: 'images/' + i,
    size: new _g.Size(26, 26),
    origin: new _g.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new _g.Point(0, 0)
};

// Our custom marker
s.ICONS[i] = new _g.Marker({
    "position"  : [the end google.maps.LatLng() of the polyline],
    "icon"      : image,
    "draggable" : false,
    "map"       : s.instance,
    "anchor"    : new _g.Point(0, 0)
});
```

I have tried changing the size and the origin but it still seems to revolve around the polyline rather than staying at the end (or just a few pixels away from the end of the line) Can anyone help me with this?

[EDIT]
You'll get the tutorials the first visit, just refresh for it to go away and click to make a square or something anywhere on the map, you'll see the issues I'm having once you've placed 4 points.

Comment: Where does "position" (l) come from?

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is part of the function (the rest is just type checking) and l = a Google LatLng object.

Comment: But where does it come from?  Why do you think it is the end of the Polyline?

Comment: It's the end point of my poly line, I've used the same latLng object as the end point of the line so that the icon stays there but it in-fact revolves around it.